# Add JS to header despite JavascriptFilteredIntoFooterHeaderResponse

Tags: javascript, wicket

I order my imported CSS and JS with a *JavascriptFilteredIntoFooterHeaderResponse*. With this Class goes all my CSS in the header and all my JS to a separate container near the `</body>` tag. But now i need to add one JS to the header but wicket pushed every JS to the footer. Knows anybody a solution for this? JavascriptFilteredIntoFooterHeaderResponse is final and can't be overriden.

**WicketApplication**

```
@Override
public void init()
{
    super.init();

    setHeaderResponseDecorator( new IHeaderResponseDecorator()
    {
        @Override
        public IHeaderResponse decorate( IHeaderResponse response )
        {
            return new JavascriptFilteredIntoFooterHeaderResponse( response, FOOTER_FILTER_NAME );
        }
    } );
}
```

**BasePage.java**

```
public BasePage()
{       
    add( new HeaderResponseFilteredResponseContainer( FOOTER_FILTER_NAME, FOOTER_FILTER_NAME ) );
}
```

**BasePage.html**

```
<body>
...
<div wicket:id="footerBucket" />
</body>
```

Comment: What Wicket version are you using?

Comment: Wicket 1.4.18 and no update to 1.5 is in view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to override JavascriptFilteredIntoFooterHeaderResponse. Just use *org.apache.wicket.resource.filtering.HeaderResponseContainerFilteringHeaderResponse* with the following constructor:

```
HeaderResponseContainerFilteringHeaderResponse(IHeaderResponse response, 
        String headerFilterName, IHeaderResponseFilter[] filters)
```

For example, if you write:

```
IHeaderResponseFilter[] filters = new IHeaderResponseFilter[] { 
        new CssAcceptingHeaderResponseFilter(HEADER_FILTER_NAME),
        new JavascriptAcceptingHeaderResponseFilter(FOOTER_FILTER_NAME) };

return new HeaderResponseContainerFilteringHeaderResponse(response, 
        HEADER_FILTER_NAME, filters);
```

it will be the same JavascriptFilteredIntoFooterHeaderResponse that you use in your code.

Here's an example of anonymous filter class that you can use instead of CssAcceptingHeaderResponseFilter to accomplish your task. File "script-for-the-header.js" is the script that you'd like to have in the header.

```
new CssAcceptingHeaderResponseFilter(HEADER_FILTER_NAME) {

    @Override
    public boolean acceptReference(ResourceReference ref) {
        if (!Strings.isEmpty(ref.getName()) && ref.getName().equals("script-for-the-header.js")) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return super.acceptReference(ref);
        }
    }
}
```

To better organize your code you may also consider overriding HeaderResponseContainerFilteringHeaderResponse (if you haven't guessed yet, it's also the parent of JavascriptFilteredIntoFooterHeaderResponse). See source code in [JavascriptFilteredIntoFooterHeaderResponse.java](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/apache/wicket/wicket/1.4.15/wicket-1.4.15-sources.jar!/org/apache/wicket/resource/filtering/JavascriptFilteredIntoFooterHeaderResponse.java?format=ok) for details.

Comment: Thank your for the nice tip Artem. I extend the CssAcceptingHeaderResponseFilter class to accept also some concrete JS files. Now goes each css file to the header + some concrete js files. All other js files go to my footer container.